# How can you change the background color of your hex codes to match the actual hex color in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, color-scheme, jetbrains-ide

[image]My buddy changed the color of his hex colors in PhpStorm but I can't find where he did it.  I found in the preferences that you can change the color of your Editor but their is no option to change the hex codes to show the color they represent.  My buddy doesn't remember where he found the setting.

Comment: In the picture above is what I found.  But again I only see an option to choose what color you want all hex colors to be not an option to be the color they represent.

Comment: So you are talking about CSS colors...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance
2. Show CSS color preview as background

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! You're amazing exactly what I was looking for.